# Change text for a node in the kendo treeview

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var dataSource = treeView.dataSource;
var dataItem = dataSource.get(parseInt($('#nodeId' + '@guid').val(), 10));
var node = treeView.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
treeView.select(node);
treeView.text(node, "ChangedText");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it with the treeview's `text` method, or by setting the property on the data item:

```
var tree = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: inlineDefault,
    loadOnDemand: false
}).data("kendoTreeView");

// change using treeView.findByText and treeView.text
$("#change").click(function () {
    var searchString = "Sofas";

    $(tree.findByText(searchString)).each(function () {
        tree.text(this, "Thrones");
    });
});

// change using the data source
$("#change2").click(function () {
    var searchString = "Sofas";

    var dataItem = tree.dataSource.data()[0].items[1];
    dataItem.set("text", "Thrones");    
});
```

You'll need to set the `loadOnDemand` option to false to search the tree, because otherwise the DOM elements are only created when the relevant branch is expanded.

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/hqp57/))